# Test for a Valid Instance of java.time.LocalDate using Clojure Spec

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I am trying to use Clojure Spec to define a data structure containing a java.time.LocalDate element:

```
(s/def :ex/first-name string?)
(s/def :ex/last-name string?)
(s/def :ex/birth-date (s/valid? inst? (java.time.LocalDate/now)))

(s/def :ex/person
  (s/keys :req [:ex/first-name
                :ex/last-name
                :ex/birth-date]))

(def p1 #:ex{:first-name "Jenny"
             :last-name  "Barnes"
             :birth-date (java.time.LocalDate/parse "1910-03-15")})

(println p1)
```

produces the following output

```
#:ex{:first-name Jenny, :last-name Barnes, :birth-date #object[java.time.LocalDate 0x4ed4f9db 1910-03-15]}
```

However, when I test to see if p1 conforms to the :ex/person spec, it fails:

```
(s/valid? :ex/person p1)
ClassCastException java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  clojure.spec.alpha/spec-impl/reify--1987 (alpha.clj:875)
```

Looking closer at the [Clojure examples for inst?](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/inst_q#example-5925960be4b093ada4d4d71f), I see:

```
(inst? (java.time.Instant/now))
;;=> true
(inst? (java.time.LocalDateTime/now))
;;=> false
```

However, I don't see an obvious reason as to why that returns false. This seems to be the root of my issue, but I have not found a solution and would like some help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`instance?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/instance_q)- and your example fails, because in:

```
(s/def :ex/birth-date (s/valid? inst? (java.time.LocalDate/now)))
```

this part `(s/valid? inst? (java.time.LocalDate/now))` should be a function (predicate), not boolean. The full code:

```
(s/def :ex/first-name string?)
(s/def :ex/last-name string?)
(s/def :ex/birth-date #(instance? java.time.LocalDate %))

(s/def :ex/person
  (s/keys :req [:ex/first-name
                :ex/last-name
                :ex/birth-date]))

(def p1 #:ex{:first-name "Jenny"
             :last-name  "Barnes"
             :birth-date (java.time.LocalDate/parse "1910-03-15")})

(s/valid? :ex/person p1)
=> true
```

[`inst?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/inst_q) won't work here, because `Inst` is a protocol, used to extend `java.util.Date` and `java.time.Instant`:

```
(defprotocol Inst
  (inst-ms* [inst]))

(extend-protocol Inst
  java.util.Date
  (inst-ms* [inst] (.getTime ^java.util.Date inst)))

(defn inst?
  "Return true if x satisfies Inst"
  {:added "1.9"}
  [x]
  (satisfies? Inst x))

(extend-protocol clojure.core/Inst
  java.time.Instant
  (inst-ms* [inst] (.toEpochMilli ^java.time.Instant inst)))
```

And you can use [`satisfies?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/satisfies_q) to check whether some object satisfies given protocol:

```
(satisfies? Inst (java.time.LocalDate/parse "1910-03-15"))
=> false
```

Comment: This does work. However, I still would like to know why `(inst? (java.time.LocalDateTime/now))` returns false.

Comment: Thank you. I misread `inst?` as "instance of". Too many years of Java programming to break...